# Realpath() warning joomla php

Tags: php, joomla, warnings, phpexcel

I have created a php file that exports data to an excel file using PHPExcel.
On my localhost everything works fine but when I upload it to the live site I get :

```
    Warning: realpath() [function.realpath]: SAFE MODE Restriction in effect. The script whose uid is 755 is not allowed to access /tmp owned by uid 0 in
```

I'm not sure if I can fix this with a simple CHMOD or I have to call my server administrator

I am using joomla 1.7.1 if it matters

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like 'safe mode' is restricting access to a folder. You need to either disable safe mode or add the folder to the allowed directories. Someone with a similar problem here < http://forums.gplhost.com/phpBB2/image-vp8763.html> .

I suggest you look at your server logs for a more detailed error.Look for instances of open base dir error messages.

Comment: thank you for your answer. but im not sure i understand... i went into the link you posted and i cant seem to find the files they are talking about and i dont think i can ask my server admin to turn "safe mode" off for the server... i haven't asked to him yet but it seems over the top...

Comment: Basically, you need to check this issue is down to your script trying to access a folder it's not allowed to. Check your logs for an open basedir error. If you find it, you need to either change the foldee you are writing your files to or disable the open basedir directive. Check php.net/manual/en/ini.core and search for 'basedir'.

Comment: im sorry that im "digging" i have never had to deal with thees files. i dont know how i get to them. i cant seem to find them in my FTP. are thees files suppose to be available to me?

Comment: Those files would be available to the system administrator. I assume from what you say that you dont have that level of access. The only other thing I can think of is that you check where you are creating the file on the server and that, if you can configure your script, you try to make sure the file is created within the folder of your website and not higher up in the folder structure.

Comment: Thank you so very much. Apparently i was trying to save the file to the servers root tmp folder witch obviously i don't have permissions for. I would have never have thought of that. Have a merry Christmas and a happy new-year :)